# SQL: How to ALTER a COLUMN so that it uses a PK SEQUENCE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `PaperTrailDocumentControlSetting` that works as expected on my **local** database, but doesn't work on our **production** database.  I need to alter the table on the **production**  database so that it matches the **local** database table.

```
------------------------------------
| PaperTrailDocumentControlSetting |
------------------------------------
|     id
|    etc...
------------------------------------
```

The error occurs when I try insert a row, the `id` column is being set to `null` because it is not set to use its sequence. e.g:

> ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 163898, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null). SQL state: 23502

The table on the **local** database has it's `id` as:

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('papertraildocumentcontrolsetting_id_seq'::regclass),
```

The table on the **production** database has it's `id` as:

```
id bigint NOT NULL,
```

I have tried the following SQL command to alter the column:

```
ALTER TABLE PaperTrailDocumentControlSetting ALTER COLUMN id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('papertraildocumentcontrolsetting_id_seq'::regclass);
```

But that returns the following:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "bigint"
LINE 1: ... PaperTrailDocumentControlSetting ALTER COLUMN id bigint NOT...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 62
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the [`ALTER TABLE` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) you can't change the whole column specification in on go, but have to specify what you want to change.

I think this should work:

```sql
ALTER TABLE PaperTrailDocumentControlSetting 
   ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT 
   nextval('papertraildocumentcontrolsetting_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: thank you, I was missing the `SET` keyword.